# Scan function by reference or by value

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
statement := `SELECT id from source where mgmt = $1 `
var exists string
errUnique := dr.db.QueryRow(statement, mgmt).Scan(exists)
if errUnique != nil && errUnique != sql.ErrNoRows {
    return errUnique
}
```

The above code works for me. However, shouldn't my  `.Scan(&exists)` have a by reference? This does not work. On the other hand, when I change exists to a bool as seen here `var exists bool` the `.Scan(&exists)` suddenly works. Why isn't the string `exists` and `.Scan(&exists)` not working?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Row.Scan . it's all about `interface{}` https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types

Comment: Should I then maybe change my exists string to a NullString? @Deadooshka

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan use a pointer type `*string`. all conversions found in [`convertAssignRows`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a10b4cff91cb5d26e2049f6efc20349aa4d50d20/src/database/sql/convert.go#L217) function

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? Does `exists` get populated with data? Also, by "does not work"? What is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have `exists` be the same type as, or a compatible type to, the type of the value you are retrieving from the database.

Since you're selecting the `id` column, I will assume that it is an `integer`, and therefore you should declare exists as follows `var exists int`. If, however, you want to find out whether a row is present in the table or not you would generally use a query of the form:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM source WHERE mgmt= $1)
```

(at least in postgres, I'm not sure what db you're using)

[`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS):

> The argument of EXISTS is an arbitrary SELECT statement, or subquery.
>   The subquery is evaluated to determine whether it returns any rows. If
>   it returns at least one row, the result of EXISTS is “true”; if the
>   subquery returns no rows, the result of EXISTS is “false”.

Then your Go code would something like this:

```
query := `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM source WHERE mgmt = $1)`

var exists bool
if err := dr.db.QueryRow(query, mgmt).Scan(&exists); err != nil {
    return err
}

if exists {
    // already taken
} else {
    // unique
}
```

Also note that since `EXISTS` always returns a boolean value you don't have to check the error against `sql.ErrNoRows`, if you do get an error it would not be that one.

Comment: I think the question is about how is it possible that `.Scan(exists)` (as opposed to `.Scan(&exists)`) "works"

Comment: But @Jay266, it might work in the sense that there is no error, but it won't put the result into `exists`

Comment: @Jay266 I was trying to answer your last question *("Why isn't the string `exists` and `.Scan(&exists)` not working?")*, and if the double negative in that question was a typo then I think this is a legitimate answer.

Comment: @ııı I'm having a hard time believing that it "works" in the sense that it doesn't return any error.

Comment: @Jay266 passing a non-pointer string to `Scan` returns an error `sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "email": destination not a pointer` on my machine when using Go's `database/sql` and `lib/pq` as the db driver. If, on your setup, you do not get an error then please provide the Go version you're using along with what libraries you're using to connect and query the database.

Comment: it's there https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a10b4cff91cb5d26e2049f6efc20349aa4d50d20/src/database/sql/convert.go#L383