# Cleanest way to check if record in database exist, without caring about its contents (scan into nothing)?

Tags: sql, go, go-sqlite3

I have a piece of code that checks whether or not the requested key exists in the database. Its contents are therefore not important in that particular place.

The best way I know how to check for it is to try to `Scan()` it and see if it returned an error, which leaves the declared and initialized variable which it scanned into unused. My question is, is this the cleanest and most minimal way to solve that problem?

Relevant code (using `database/sql` from the standard library):

```golang
var content string
err := db.QueryRowContext(
    ctx,
    querySelect,
    hashKey,
).Scan(&content)

return err == nil
```

Scanning into `io.Discard` doesn't work here as it reports "destination not a pointer".

Comment: Use `SELECT EXISTS(...)`. See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49449519/965900), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54753257/965900).

Comment: I've accidentally discovered that `Scan(nil)` seemingly works. I guess now it's between checking for two types of errors that `Scan()` can then return or making a slightly longer query with the `SELECT 1` solution.